# babel-preset-expo not working with react and es2015 presets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I am fairly new to JavaScript and react and completely new to react native. I am trying to combine a React application and React Native one, the React Native app was created with the "create-react-native-app"-command. So it uses babel-preset-expo while the React app uses react and es2015 as presets in the babelrc file. When I try to combine them, the react native app gives errors. I read in the Babel docs that the order of the presets matter, I have tried to combine them in all possible orders but it still gives me errors such as

"RangeErro:Maximum call stack size exceeded" or "createTHREEViewClass.js: Missing class properties transform".

This is the babelrc file:

```
  {
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo","react","es2015"],
    "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
    }
  }
}
```

Is the babel-preset-expo not compatible with anything else or what am I missing??

Comment: I would just go with `babel-preset-expo` and no combinations.